# An Alternative Proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem(?)

Tags: real-analysis, fake-proofs

My version of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem states that:

"A bounded sequence in $\Bbb R$ always have a convergent subsequence."

Till now, I only knew one or two standard proofs that are always cited in books.

But suddenly when I , out of just sheer curiosity tried proving it, I found that there is probably a much shorter and concise way of proving it. Surprisingly enough, till now, never did I encounter this way of proving.

I will state that hereby:

Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence. This means, $X=(x_n)$ and there exists a real number $M$ such that $|x_n|\leq M,\forall n\in\Bbb N.$

This means, that the set $X$ or the sequence is bounded above. As the Set $X\neq \emptyset,$ we can conclude by the Axiom of Completeness that $s=\sup X\in\Bbb R$ exists.

We claim, that $s$ is a limit point of $X$. In other words, the claim implies, that there exists a convergent subsequence of the sequence $(x_n).$

For every $\frac{1}{n}$ (,where $n\in\Bbb N$) we choose, an $a_n\in X$ such that, $s-\frac 1n\lt a_n\leq s\lt s+\frac{1}{n},$ and the existence of such an $a_n$ is justified, as $s$ is a supremum. Continuing like this, we obtain a subsequence $(a_n)$ of $(x_n)(=X).$

We claim $\lim a_n=s.$

For any $\epsilon\gt 0$ there exists an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0}\lt\epsilon$ (By Archimedean Property). Now, we have, $\exists n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $$s-\epsilon\lt s-\frac {1}{n_0}\lt a_{n_0}\leq s\lt s+\frac{1}{n_0}\lt s+\epsilon,$$ and if $n\geq n_0$ then, $s-\epsilon\lt s-\frac{1}{n_0}\leq s-\frac{1}{n}\lt a_n\lt s+\frac 1n\leq s+\frac{1}{n_0}\lt s+\epsilon.$ This proves that $\lim a_n=s.$

Again, this establishes our initial claim as well as $(a_n)$ is a convergent subsequence of $(x_n).$

---

I don't understand whether this really is an alternative proof or not? I haven't been able to find any errors till now, so I want to know if this a valid argument?

Comment: It looks like your proof does not cover the case where the upper and lower bounds are 
 isolated points, e.g. the infinite set $\{ -1, 1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \cdots\}$

Comment: One flaw that I see is that you didn't show that the $(a_n)$ are all coming from different elements of $(x_n)$. A counterexample of your proof would be the sequence $(1/n)$ for n natural: it has a supremum, 1, but no subsequence approaching it.

Comment: You say you can find points $a_n$ in the set arbitrarily close to the supremum, but that is not the case when the supremum is isolated.  The essence of your proof is OK but you need to exclude isolated points.  Doing so I expect brings your version of the proof to look much like others.  In essence the supremum or infimum need not themselves be limit points.  Consider the set $\{\pm 1, \pm \tfrac{1}{2}, \pm \tfrac{1}{3}, \cdots\}$.  The only limit point is zero, right in the middle of the set.

Comment: If you apply your logic to $\{ \pm 1, \pm\tfrac{1}{2}, \cdots\}$ then the subsequence you obtain is $1,1,1,1,1,\cdots$ which is not a  proper subsequence.  If you call any a repeated element a subsequence then every non empty set, bounded or not, finite or not has a convergent subsequqnce.

Comment: Let $X=\{\pm1, \pm\tfrac{1}{2}, \pm\tfrac{1}{3}, \cdots\}$.  Then $s = \sup X = 1$.  The sequence $a_n$ you obtain consists of the points $a_1, 1, 1, \cdots$, where $a_1$ could be any one of several choices, but all subsequent points have to be $1$.  This is in line with the procedure you set out but is not a subsequence.

Comment: @WADon Oh, now I get it. If you consider posting this as an answer , I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One flaw that I see is that you didn't show that the $\{a_n\}$ are all distinct elements of $X$.  You say you can find points $a_n$ in the set arbitrarily close to the supremum, but when the supremum is isolated you just end up with the same point repeated.

For example, consider the set $X = \{\pm1,\pm\tfrac{1}{2},\pm\tfrac{1}{3},\cdots\}$  The supremum $s$ is the point $1$.  But following the procedure in your argument, the subsequence you obtain is $a_1, 1, 1, \cdots$, where there is a wide choice for $a_1$ but all subsequent points have to be $1$.  That is not a (proper) subsequence.

The fix is to divide $X$ by half repeatedly and every time you do so one of the sub-division will always be infinite.  The subdivisions get smaller and smaller  (because $X$ is bounded) and being infinite always contain one element.  Choosing one element of these divisions (there is always a fresh choice because the set is infinite) produces a convergent subsequence which may or may not converge to the supremum.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Precisely, my proof becomes erring if, the supremum is in the set, correct? The proof is correct only if, the supremum of the sequence is not a part of it.

Comment: It still needs a small modification.  You must choose $a_n$ satisfying $\max(s - 1/n, a_{n-1}) < a_n < s$ - possible because $s \not \in X$ and $s$is the supremum.  The max step is needed so you don't choose $a_n = a_{n-1}$.  In fact where $s$ is in $X$ this can still work if $s$ is a limit point, but the conclusion is uninteresting - it is no surprise to find a convergent subsequence if you already know $s$ is a limit point.

Answer (score 0):

I find easier use the result: "A bounded infinite set of real line has an accumulation point"(see similar question). Stated this, set $A=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots x_n,\ldots\}$, if $A$ is infinite, then the accumulation point is limit of a subsequence. If $A$ is finite, one of the sets $\{n\in N : x_n= x_i\}$ $i=1,2,\ldots k $ is infinite and we have the converging subsequence.